# Hibernate Search programmatic API HTMLStripCharFilterFactory

Tags: hibernate-search

I want to setup Hibernate Search (5.5.1.Final) using Programmatic API.

With annotations i write

```
@AnalyzerDefs({
    @AnalyzerDef(name = "el",
        charFilters = {@CharFilterDef(factory = HTMLStripCharFilterFactory.class)},
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class), 
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = GreekLowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class, 
                params = {@Parameter(name="words", value="stopwords-gr.txt")}),
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class, 
                params = {@Parameter(name="minGramSize", value = "3"),@Parameter(name="maxGramSize", value = "15"),@Parameter(name="side", value = "front")})
        }
    )
})
```

With Programmatic API i write

```
SearchMapping mapping = new SearchMapping();
mapping.analyzerDef("el", StandardTokenizerFactory.class)
    .filter(StandardFilterFactory.class)
    .filter(GreekLowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
    .filter(StopFilterFactory.class)
    .filter(EdgeNGramFilterFactory.class)
        .param("minGramSize", "3")
        .param("maxGramSize", "15")
        .param("side", "front");
```

But i cannot figure out how i will use the HTMLStripCharFilterFactory.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, that you cannot. When the `charFilters` option got introduced as part of [HSEARCH-477](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-477), it was missed to also add it to the programmatic API. So the functionality just does not exist yet. I created [HSEARCH-2199](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2199) as a feature request to add this functionality.